# Cant RDP to laptop using AAD account

Tags: windows, azure, azure-active-directory, rdp, windows-11

i recently got a new laptop and installed windows 11 pro on it. At the setup i signed in with my work email. then i turned on RDP and was able to connect. after a week of working using RDP i cant RDP anymore. i get the error "The logon attempt failed" i havent changed my password of my email or anything.

i tried using rdp using these usernames
AzureAD\username
AzureAD\Company@email.com
.\AzureAD\username
.\AzureAD\Company@email.com

i also tried adding this to a .rdp file
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62307900/remote-machine-is-aad-but-the-logon-attempt-failed)
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
authentication level:i:2

and now i even reinstalled windows to see if that fixed it. which it didnt.
does anyone know what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error `The logon attempt failed`  may occur for several reasons you are unable to access into RDP in your Windows 11 Pro laptop.

To resolve the issue, check the below steps:

When I attempt to RDP VM in Azure with AAD credentials, I got login attempt failed error.

When creating virtual machine and login with Azure AD ensure that the extension `AADLoginForWindows extension.` is ***Provisioning succeeded*** like below:

[image]

[image]

To authorize log into the VM, ensure that you have assigned RBAC role assignment of **Virtual Machine Administrator Login** and **Virtual Machine User Login**

[image]

Verify whether your computer or virtual machine has joined Azure AD by logging into the Azure VM, open Settings and select Accounts -> Access for work or school. Check your PCs are connected to Azure AD and connect to organization Azure AD.

In system properties -> Remote -> ***Untick*** Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication like below:

[image]

Add Azure AD user to the remote desktop users group on the VM Refer
Additionally, you should make sure that per-user multi-factor authentication is turned off for the user account as it is not supported for Azure AD-joined VMs.

Modify the RDP file and add a username and domain prompts the user to enter the credentials directly like below:

[image]

```
authentication level:i:2
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
username:s:USERNAME@DOMAIN.onmicrosoft.com
domain:s:AzureAD
```

Using Azure AD-account on VM `AzureAD\USERNAME@DOMAIN.onmicrosoft.com`  login successfully like below:

[image]